# React Native Stateless component saying undefined

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a component using React Native like so:

```
export class IndicatorOverlay extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>text</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

The above works, but when I try to make it stateless like so...

```
export default ({ text = 'text' }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I get the following error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but I just can't see it. I use a similar stateless component in a React web app and it's fine.

Using react 16.0.0-alpha.6 and react-native 0.43.2, and am seeing this error in the iPhone simulator.

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: I've encountered similar kind of behavior. But try `const IndicatorOverlay = (...) => {...}` and then `export default IndicatorOverlay`. It should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely because the first example is a named export, while the second one is a default one therefore the way need to import them is different.

Assuming you import your module like this:

```
import { IndicatorOverlay } from 'IndicatorOverlay';
```

you have two options. Either:

1) change the way you import your module (since the stateless component is a default export now):

```
import IndicatorOverlay from 'IndicatorOverlay';
```

2) keep the import intact, but refactor your stateless component to something like this:

```
export const IndicatorOverlay = ({text = 'text'}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

You can make it more DRY btw:

```
export const IndicatorOverlay = ({ text = 'text' }) => (
  <View>
    <Text>{text}</Text>
  </View>
);
```

You can read more about imports and exports on MDN:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: amazing! Thank you. And +1 for making it a little more dry... :)